# Feature hashing and interpretability

Tags: feature-engineering, importance, hash

I am working on a classification project where nearly all raw features (~30) are categorical such as category ID, city, or responsible team ID, some with cardinality > 600. I am using a feature hasher to encode those with high cardinality and One-Hot-Encoding (OHE) for those with smaller ones (up to 30 different values).

While OHE allows some interpretability out of the importance score assigned by the supervised algorithm (tree based in my case), I wonder if there is a way to revert back the hashed feature to interpret the importance of the original feature.
Does any of you know how this can be achieved?

I was thinking of isolating that feature only and using its OHE representation as a predictor and start from there, but with 200,000 samples and 8 target classes, I am not sure how meaningful that will be.